# Let me go back and change my decision!

Tags: feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change edit approval/rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88096/change-edit-approval-rejection)

I just clicked "Looks good" on an answer, then immediately realised it should have been a comment. When I hit back, I couldn't recast my vote, so I visited the question to flag it as not an answer. If this system keeps track of my good "Looks good" votes vs my bad ones, like flagging does, I've just damaged my own "Looks good" score.

Let us go back and change our decisions - even if it's restricted only to ones we've only just voted on.

Comment: Sam's reply on the dupe is pretty much up to date and I tend to agree with it. Those mistakes are pretty rare. It needs 2 to approve (or reject) so usually two others will "override" your wrong decision. :)

Comment: It's a dupe then. I'll leave this undeleted so it can be closed as such and be a breadcrumb to that answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: You can also add your own vote, though we'll still need 3 other users or 1 mod to close this as duplicate. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I actually don't have an option to cast a close vote. I only have share/edit/delete/flag.

Comment: Hmm.. probably not enough reputation - no big deal, looks like other users here are doing the job just fine.. :)