# Can voting for an edit be undone?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change edit approval/rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88096/change-edit-approval-rejection)

I've developed [a script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3684/suggestion-status-a-userscript-to-view-the-status-of-your-suggested-edits) which allows you to view the status of your edit suggestion at a glance. (*Accepted* / *Rejected* or *not yet processed*.)

Since it generates [quite a lot of traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESooe.png) to StackOverflow because it checks the status of each edit suggestion at page (re)load, I intend to cache the status of the edit suggestion.

However, since I am not eligible to approve edits yet, I don't know if the approval / rejection of an edit can be undone. Are edit approvals / rejects permanent?

**TL;DR**: Can the status of an edit change after it's been approved / rejected?

**Note:** Although I have searched for a couple of minutes, I haven't found any similar question. However, because this question may have been asked in a different form it might be possible somebody did already ask this. If so, can you please share a link to the relevant answer?

Comment: The larger issue is that you should be using the API to get the information you need, since the site will likely frown on that less. Unfortunately to do so you'd have to jump through a few hoops, since the ID reflected in the URL isn't the *actual* ID of the suggested edit anymore.

Comment: @TimStone: It's not _that_ easy to get blocked: ["Reloading a full page about **9** times within a short period of time will have you temporarily blocked."](http://stackapps.com/q/3684)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to cache status.

Rolling the post back, you can undo *the changes* of a suggested edit. However, this does **not** affect the status of the suggested edit itself.

Answer (score 6):

Approvals and rejections are permanent and cannot be undone.